# JavaScript Subtract Time Diffrence

Tags: javascript

I just made the following code and are having a few issues with it. The entire idea of the project is to be able determine how much time you have left in a school period or until a period starts. I first stored the users time as a variable and isolated the current hours and minutes using a sub string. Here is the code for that.

```
//Get current date.
var now = new Date();
//Make the date only hours and minutes But the issue is there is a semicolon (:) in between them.
var myTime = now.toString().substr(16,5)
```

The issue with that was I was left with a semicolon that prevents this entire thing from working.

After I get the hours and minutes isolated and stored as variable I need to tell if the users time is within the school day. I  did that by making a conditional if statement that im not sure was done successfully.

```
if (myTime > startday || myTime < endday) {
```

Here I ONLY want the statement to work if the users current time, also known as myTime is GREATER than startday and LESS than endday. This is because startday is stored as the start of my school day time and endday is stored as the end time of my school day. If the users current time dosent meet this requirement it then goes to the else statement which says school hasnt started yet.

Here is the rest of the code if you want to see and make any suggestions.

```
//Get current date.
var now = new Date();
//Make the date only hours and minutes But the issue is there is a semicolen (:) in between them.
var myTime = now.toString().substr(16,5)
//For Testing Purposes.
console.log(myTime);

//All the periods throught my school day.
var startday = 0745;
var period1end = 0834;
var period1transition = 0838;
var period2end = 0930;
var period2transition = 0934;
var period3end = 1023;
var period3transition = 1027;
var period4end = 1116;
var period4transition = 1120;
var period5end = 1238;
var period5transition = 1242;
var period6end = 1331;
var period6transition = 1335;
var period7end = 1425;
var endday = 1425;

//The big boy, I will tell you my thought proccess as I go
function myFunction() {
//Here I ONLY want the statement to work if the users current time, also known as myTime is GREATER than startday and less than endday. This is because startday is stored as the start of my school day and endday is the end of the day. If the users current time dosent meet this requirement it then goes to the else statement which says school hasnt started yet.
    if (myTime > startday || myTime < endday) {
        console.log("Test");
//The purpose of this statement is the following. If the users time is LESS than the time period 1 ends it will then subtract period1's time from the users current time.
    } else if (myTime < period1end) {
        var timeleft = (period1end-myTime);
        console.log("There is" + timeleft + "mintues left in the period." );
//The purpose of this statement is if the users time is in between a period, also known as period1transition, it says the amount of time until the next period starts.
    } else if (myTime < period1transition) {
        var timeleft = (period1transition-myTime);
        console.log("There is" + timeleft + "mintues left until the next period starts." );
    } else if (myTime < period2end) {
        var timeleft = (period2end-myTime);
        console.log("There is" + timeleft + "mintues left in the period." );
    } else if (myTime < period2transition) {
        var timeleft = (period2transition-myTime);
        console.log("There is" + timeleft + "mintues left until the next period starts." );
    } else if (myTime < period3end) {
        var timeleft = (period3end-myTime);
        console.log("There is" + timeleft + "mintues left in the period." );
    } else if (myTime < period3transition) {
        var timeleft = (period3transition-myTime);
        console.log("There is" + timeleft + "mintues left until the next period starts." );
    } else if (myTime < period4end) {
        var timeleft = (period4end-myTime);
        console.log("There is" + timeleft + "mintues left in the period." );
    } else if (myTime < period4transition) {
        var timeleft = (period4transition-myTime);
        console.log("There is" + timeleft + "mintues left until the next period starts." );
    } else if (myTime < period5end) {
        var timeleft = (period5end-myTime);
        console.log("There is" + timeleft + "mintues left in the period." );
    } else if (myTime < period5transition) {
        var timeleft = (period5transition-myTime);
        console.log("There is" + timeleft + "mintues left until the next period starts." );
    } else if (myTime < period6end) {
        var timeleft = (period6end-myTime);
        console.log("There is" + timeleft + "mintues left in the period." );
    } else if (myTime < period6transition) {
        var timeleft = (period6transition-myTime);
        console.log("There is" + timeleft + "mintues left until the next period starts." );
    } else if (myTime < period7end) {
        var timeleft = (period7end-myTime);
        console.log("There is" + timeleft + "mintues left in the period." );
    } else if (myTime < period7transition) {
        var timeleft = (period7transition-myTime);
        console.log("There is" + timeleft + "mintues left until the next period starts." );
    } else {
//If the users time is not greater than the startday and less than the endday it simply says the following.
        console.log("School Has Not Started Yet");
    }
  //forget about this.
// document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myTime;
}
```

Thanks

Zach

Comment: My suggestion is that you ditch all that and start over using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: @JohnnyHK Will it be that much easier?

Comment: @zmalter99 Yes it will

Comment: @JohnnyHK I personally find it easier to just use the `new Date().getTime()`, as seen below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work with minutes only instead of the combination hours-minutes, as the latter is much harder to calculate with.

Also, your code will have less repetition if you use an array for storing the different periods.

Here is how you could do it:

```js
//Get current date & midnight
var now = new Date();
var midnight = new Date();
midnight.setHours(0,0,0,0);
//Get number of minutes that passed since midnight:
var myTime = Math.floor((now.getTime() - midnight.getTime()) / 60000);
//For Testing Purposes.
console.log(myTime + ' minutes passed since midnight.');

function minutes(hour, min) {
    return hour * 60 + min;
}

//All the periods throughout my school day.
var periods = [
    { start: minutes( 7, 45), end: minutes( 8, 34) },
    { start: minutes( 8, 38), end: minutes( 9, 30) },
    { start: minutes( 9, 34), end: minutes(10, 23) },
    { start: minutes(10, 27), end: minutes(11, 16) },
    { start: minutes(11, 20), end: minutes(12, 38) },
    { start: minutes(12, 42), end: minutes(13, 31) },
    { start: minutes(13, 35), end: minutes(14, 25) },
];

function myFunction(myTime, periods) {
    periods.every(function (period, i) {
        if (myTime < period.start) {
            if (i == 0) {
                console.log('School has not started yet');
            } else {
                var timeLeft = period.start - myTime;
                console.log("There are " + timeLeft + 
                            " minutes left until period " + (i+1) + " starts.");
            }
        } else if (myTime < period.end) {
            var timeLeft = period.end - myTime;
            console.log("There are " + timeLeft + 
                        " minutes left until period " + (i+1) + " is over.");
        } else if (i == periods.length - 1) {
            console.log('School has finished for today');
        } else {
            return true; // keep looking for the right period
        }
    });
}

myFunction(myTime, periods);
```

Comment: Can you explain the array? @trincot

Comment: What about it ?

Comment: Why are you doing "minutes ( number, number)" @trincot

Comment: To get the time in one unit of measure (minutes), not two (hours, minutes).

Answer (score 0):

Falling asleep as I write this, but it may be way easier if you break each concept down into bite sized chunks. Also, don't work with *String* if you can work with *Number*, it will make your life easier;

Useful functions for getting *Numbers* from a *Date* in what you've written

```
const now = new Date();
const day = now.getDay();
const hh = now.getHours();
const mm = now.getMinutes();
```

So you could write something like this, where the following concepts have been broken down into their own chunks

- *hh:mm* time, how far away it is from some other time `hh` and `mm`
- A period time-slot, named, how far away it is (until/since) and whether it is in progress
- A timetable, days of the week, lists of time slots

```
class TimeTableTime {
    constructor(hh, mm) {
        this.hh = hh;
        this.mm = mm;
    }
    until(hh, mm) { // ms
        return (this.hh - hh) * 60 * 60 * 1000
            + (this.mm - mm) * 60 * 1000;
    }
}

class TimeTableSlot {
    constructor(startHh, startMm, endHh, endMm, name) {
        this.start = new TimeTableTime(startHh, startMm);
        this.end = new TimeTableTime(endHh, endMm);
        this.name = name;
    }
    until(hh, mm) {
        return this.start.until(hh, mm);
    }
    since(hh, mm) {
        return -this.end.until(hh, mm);
    }
    current(hh, mm) {
        return this.start.until(hh, mm) <= 0
            && this.end.until(hh, mm) > 0;
    }
}
```

```
const timetable = {
    0: [], // Sunday
    1: [
        new TimeTableSlot(7, 45, 8, 34, 'Period 1'),
        new TimeTableSlot(8, 34, 8, 38, 'Period 1 Transition'),

        new TimeTableSlot(8, 38, 9, 30, 'Period 2'),
        new TimeTableSlot(9, 30, 9, 34, 'Period 2 Transition')
    ],
    6: [] // Saturday
};
// populate other days with example data from Monday
(function () {
    let i;
    for (i = 2; i < 6; ++i) timetable[i] = timetable[1];
}());
```

```
// Ideally, you'd also make TimeTable a class and these would be on it's prototype
function current() {
    const now = new Date();
    const day = now.getDay();
    const hh = now.getHours();
    const mm = now.getMinutes();

    return timetable[day].filter(slot => slot.current(hh, mm));
}

function next() {
    const now = new Date();
    const day = now.getDay();
    const hh = now.getHours();
    const mm = now.getMinutes();

    let delta = Infinity;
    return timetable[day].reduce((soonest, testSlot) => {
        let delta2 = testSlot.until(hh, mm);
        if (delta2 < 0) {
            return soonest;
        }
        if (delta2 === delta) {
            soonest.push(testSlot);
            return soonest;
        }
        if (delta2 < delta) {
            delta = delta2;
            return [testSlot];
        }

        return soonest;
    }, []);
}
```